# How to get params in URL with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I followed a tutorial online that taught me how to create a form and display the user input.

However, I would like to know how can I GET the params in a URL.

For example, with the following URL "http://localhost:8181?fname=joseph&gender=male", how do I GET the fname and gender and display it?

Or even more, how is the whole thing set up? In my understanding, node.js creates a local server to display a website.

I tried research on express and request, but I still can't find anything and my understanding on node.js is terrible too.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: well... as written those aren't query parameters. You're missing the `?`

Comment: Duplicate question and malformed URL.  Similar question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377199/getting-longitude-latitude-from-a-link-in-javascript/37377343#37377343

Comment: my mistake, the URL should be localhost:8181?fname=joseph&gender=make, is that correct? and can someone just give me a basic idea on how to do it? I have no idea at all.

Comment: Read the linked answer and comments.  You're looking for a url parsing library.  Everything past the ? is the querystring.  Those are enough keywords for you to find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned express, but did you check their documentation? Express provides `req.query` (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), so your variables should be accessible through `req.query.fname` and `req.query.gender`.

If you're trying to get variables using "vanilla" node.js, request object has `req.url`. You can parse it using built-in `url` module (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/url.html):

```
var parsedURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
```

After that, you will be able to access variables just like with express example above.